# How should I prepare for translation of zh-TW and zh-CN for Android in Titanium mobile?

Tags: titanium-mobile

In Titanium mobile, How should I prepare for translation of zh-TW and zh-CN for Android?
There is no problem on iPhone Devices when I get a message from L('hoge') in i18n, 
however on Android Devices, It recognizes a message only as zh.
How can I get a message as zh-TW or zh-CN for Android?

development environment below.

Titanium SDK G5.2.0

Android 6.01

Answer (score 0):

the reason I couldn't get a translated message properly is because I used tishadow.